# Sum all the adjacent values in an array, with some conditions

Tags: pattern-matching

I would like to sum all the adjacent values in an array that are different from 0, then replace those values with zero, apart from the first value which should be the sum.

For example having an array with `{0,0,0,10,12,5,0,1,2,0}`, should transform into `{0,0,0,27,0,0,0,3 ,0,0}`.

I have a badly formed loop that works, but it isn't great.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
l = {0,0,0,10,12,5,0,1,2,0};
SequenceReplace[l, {x__ /; FreeQ[{x}, 0]} :> 
  Sequence @@ (Flatten@{Total[{x}], Table[0, Length[{x}] - 1]})]
(* {0, 0, 0, 27, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0} *)
```

Answer (score 8):

The current accepted answer will get terribly slow for larger lists.

The following s/b useful for such cases.

```
fn=With[{s = Split[#, # != 0 &]}, 
  Flatten[Total[s, {2}]*(UnitVector[Length@#, 1] & /@ s)]] &;
```

A speed comparison:

[image]

Answer (score 7):

If speed is important, the following should be much faster than the alternatives:

```
agglomerate[e_] := Module[
    {
    b = ListCorrelate[{2,-1}, Unitize[e], {-1,1}, 0],
    a = Accumulate[e],
    res = ConstantArray[0, Length@e],
    i = Range[Length[e]]
    },

    res[[Pick[i, Most@b, -1]]] = ListCorrelate[{-1,1}, a[[Pick[i, Rest@b, 2]]], -1, 0];
    res
]
```

Your example:

```
agglomerate[{0,0,0,10,12,5,0,1,2,0}]
```

> {0, 0, 0, 27, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0}

Comparison with @kglr's solution:

```
data = RandomInteger[1, 10^6] RandomInteger[10^5, 10^6];

r1 = agglomerate[data]; //AbsoluteTiming
r2 = f2[data]; //AbsoluteTiming

r1 === r2
```

> {0.106844, Null}

> {1.79474, Null}

> True

Comment: Well, that's awesome. +1

Answer (score 6):

A variation on ciao's method with comparable speeds:

```
ClearAll[f1]
f1 = With[{s = Split[#, # != 0 &]}, 
    Inner[PadRight[{#}, #2] &, Tr /@ s, Length /@ s, Join]]&;

f1 @ {0, 0, 0, 10, 12, 5, 0, 1, 2, 0}
```

> ```
> {0, 0, 0, 27, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0}
> ```

And a faster method:

```
ClearAll[f2]

f2 = With[{s = Internal`CopyListStructure[Split[Unitize@#], #]}, 
    Inner[PadRight[{#}, #2] &, Tr /@ s, Length /@ s, Join]] &;

f2 @ {0, 0, 0, 10, 12, 5, 0, 1, 2, 0}
```

> ```
> {0, 0, 0, 27, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0}
> ```

```
SeedRandom[1]
rs = RandomInteger[5, 10000];

Equal @@ Through[{f1, f2, fn}@rs]
```

> ```
>  True
> ```

```
Needs["GeneralUtilities`"]

BenchmarkPlot[{fn, f1, f2}, Range, Joined -> True, 
 ImageSize -> Large, PlotLegends -> {"fn", "f1", "f2"}]
```

[image]

Finally, a method using [`SequenceSplit`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SequenceSplit.html) (slow for long lists but worth considering):

```
ClearAll[f0]
f0 = Join @@ SequenceSplit[#, {a : Except[0] ..} :> PadRight[{+a}, Length@{a}]] &;

f0 @ {0, 0, 0, 10, 12, 5, 0, 1, 2, 0}
```

> ```
> {0, 0, 0, 27, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0}
> ```

Answer (score 3):

Does this work for you?

```
{0,0,0,10,12,5,0,1,2,0} //.{h___,a_,b_,t___}/;a!=0&&b!=0:>{h,a+b,t}
```

which instantly returns

```
{0,0,0,27,0,3,0}
```

which Natas has politely pointed out is wrong because it didn't leave zeros.

This

```
{0,0,0,10,12,5,0,1,2,0} //.{h___,a_,b_,0,t___}/;a!=0&&b!=0:>{h,a+b,0,0,t}
```

returns

```
{0,0,0,27,0,0,0,3,0,0}
```

which is closer to what was asked for except when the last two or more values in the list are non-zero.

This

```
Most[Join[{0,0,0,10,12,5,0,1,2},{0}] //.{h___,a_,b_,0,t___}/;a!=0&&b!=0:>{h,a+b,0,0,t}]
```

will deal with the case where the last item in the list is non-zero and returns

```
{0,0,0,27,0,0,0,3,0}
```

but it isn't as simple.

Comment: This does not satisfy "then replace those values with zero, apart from the first value which should be the sum".

Comment: @Natas You are right. Thank you. My mistake. And it looks like your comment has let him recognize that too. Let me see if I can fix that.

Answer (score 2):

```
list = {0,0,0,10,12,5,0,1,2,0};

Replace[
    Split[list, #2 != 0 && #1 != 0 &], 
    a : {_, __} :> {Total[a], Table[0, Length[a] - 1]}, 
    1] // Flatten
```

{0, 0, 0, 27, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0}

Answer (score 0):

**Using `FoldPairList`:**

```
Clear[accbins]
accbins[k_List] := Reverse@FoldPairList[
   Which[
     #1 != 0 && #2 != 0, {0, #1 + #2}
     , True, {#1, #2}
     ] &
   , Reverse[{0}~Join~k]
   ]

list = {0, 0, 0, 10, 12, 5, 0, 1, 2, 0};
accbins@list
```

> {0, 0, 0, 27, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0}

---

Comparison using @kglr 's code and functions:

```
f1 = With[{s = Split[#, # != 0 &]}, 
    Inner[PadRight[{#}, #2] &, Tr /@ s, Length /@ s, Join]] &;
f2 = With[{s = Internal`CopyListStructure[Split[Unitize@#], #]}, 
    Inner[PadRight[{#}, #2] &, Tr /@ s, Length /@ s, Join]] &;

SeedRandom[1];
rs = RandomInteger[5, 10000];
(First@#@rs // AbsoluteTiming)[[1]] &  /@ {f1, f2, accbins}
Equal @@ Through[{f1, f2, accbins}@rs]
```

> {0.019731, 0.00992831, 0.0619143}

> True